# I am still struggling to pass JSON data to another page. Any ideas how this is done?

Tags: php, ajax, json

Please forgive me for too many posts.

When a user clicks the btnValidate button, a call is made to a webservice. Here is that code:

```
$("#btnValidate").click(function() {

// Creating variables to hold data from textboxes

var uname = $("#user").val();
var upass = $("#pass").val();

$.post("Authorize.php",
    { data: JSON.stringify({ LoginName: uname,Password: upass }) },
    function( data )
    {
        var result = JSON.parse( data );
        if ( result != null && result.Status != null && result.Status == 0 )
        {
            // if the result was valid and the Status was 0 ("success") then login succeeded
            location.href = "listAll.php";
            return;
        }
        // analyze what went wrong:
        if ( result == null )
        {
            alert( "Invalid JSON result from validation request" );
        } else if ( result.Status == null ) {
            alert( "No Status field found in JSON result from validation request" );
        } else {
            alert( "Invalid username or password. Please try again." );
        }
     }
    );

});
</script>
```

The webservice in return, response with the following values:

```
{
    "Value": {
        "TokenId": 11,
        "LoginName": "Jerry.Mann",
        "Created": "2013-12-10T15:44:49",
        "Expires": "2013-12-31T15:44:49",
        "Token": "61f5da50-d0d9-4326-a403-f8e4798c0f0d",
        "LastUsed": "2013-12-10T15:44:49"
    },
    "Status": 0,
    "Message": null
}
```

So far so good. However, what we would like to do is pass the values in TokenId, LoginName, Created, Expires, Token, LastUsed to a page called listAll.php.

The idea of passing these values to listAll.php is so we can process them, along with other form fields and submit to the database.

I have spent a lot of time googling for answers but have not found any usable solutions so far.

The closest I came to a solution is something called data.Value.Token

Obvious because JSON structure is in a variable named data but I have not figured out how to pass this to the listAll.php page.

Beside, data.Value.Token will only pass values for tokenId.

Any ideas on how to pass the values associated with data variable to listAll.php will be greatly appreciated.

```
  <form id="Form1" method="get" >

    <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
      <tr>
              <td class="label" nowrap><label for="user">UserName:</label></td>
                <td class="field">
                  <input  maxlength="40" class="required" name="user" id="user" size="20" type="text" tabindex="2" value="" style="width:400px;color:#999;font-size:9pt;height:20px;" />
                </td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td class="label" nowrap><label for="pass">Password:</label></td>
                <td class="field">
                  <input  maxlength="40" class="required" name="pass" id="pass" size="20" type="text" tabindex="3" value="" style="width:400px;color:#999;font-size:9pt;height:20px;" />
                </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td>
          <div class="buttonSubmit">
            <span></span>
                        <input type="button" id="btnValidate"
                            style="width: 180px" value="Log In" />

          </div><br clear="all"/>

        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
```

Comment: You need to pass it in the query string or switch to a `<form>` POST.

Comment: hi @SLaks, please see the additional markup I just added to the post above.

I guess my question is, how do I add that to the form so that when I click the button, it get's passed over to the listAll.php and I can then grab the values from there?

Thank you for your prompt response.

Comment: Create `<input type="hidden">` elements.

Comment: Note that any data you pass from the client cannot be trusted.

Answer (score 1):

In your backend script, Authorize.php, you should store token into session.

js

```
$("#btnValidate").click(function(){
    $.post('Authorize.php', {$('#form').serialize()}, function(data) {
        try {
            data = JSON.parse(data);
        } catch (e) {
            return false;
        }
        if (data && 'ok' == data.result) {
            top.location = 'listAll.php';
        }
        return false;
    });
});
```

Authorize.php

```
if (empty($_POST) || isset($_POST['pass']) || !isset($_POST['login'])) {
    exit;
}

/*
 * some authorize logic
 */
if ($authorized) {
    session_start();
    $_SESSION['token'] = $token;
    echo json_encode(array('result' => 'ok'));
}
exit;
```

Comment: @Nambi, my apologies to all.

I was sent off to offsite.

One thing to bear in mind is that Authorize.php is only points to the webservice.

What I was hoping to get from you super guys is a way to grab the values of TokinId, LoginName, etc and pass to ListAll.php.

This is where stuff to be inserted into the database will be processed and I would like to the TokenId and rest of data stored into the json data variable.

Thanks to you all for your assistance.

Answer (score 0):

you may use session to pass the array to the another page.

```
session_start();
$JsonResult = $_SESSION['result']
```